# RPC call eth_getTransactionByHash fails against geth --syncmode=light --rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

Will try without `--syncmode=light` (on a different PC) to see if that command line is the culprit; if it is, this question may be answered quite easily.

**Geth version**

```
Geth
Version: 1.8.8-stable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10.2
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/home/kindaemon/go
```

**OS**

```
$ uname -a
Linux thekincasino 4.4.0-119-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Expected behaviour**

With `geth --syncmode=light --rpc` running, the command

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0x1d4775c185bbf03502fc3d8357bd536fb7bbb6425c7deafeabebc2c7305f8aec"],"id":67}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

outputs the details of the transaction with that hash.

**Actual behaviour**

That command outputs

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":null}
```

The `eth_getBlockByNumber` method does return results, in contrast.

**Steps to reproduce**

```
git clone git@github.com:ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd go-ethereum
make
./build/bin/geth --syncmode=light --rpc
```

In another terminal, run the above `curl` command and get the actual result.

Comment: Not sure, but light mode does not store transactions, only block data.

Comment: Does it fail if the transaction is for an address handled by the RPC server?